# Terraform AWS autoscaling group tagging with unique names

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I am using Terraform to spin up few instances in an an autoscaling group. The autoscale instances are dependent on the min, max and desired value passed to it. I wanted to have a unique TAG Name of each of the instances created. Please suggest.

I tried using random number but it gives the same name for all the resources created.

What I need is, lets say, for 3 resources created, the 3 instances should have something like - new-app-1, new-app-2 and new-app-3.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Autoscalling doesn't do dynamic tagging base on count, but you can use user data of the instance to retrieve the instance ID and then retag the instance like this:

```
INSTANCE_ID=$(curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id)
CURRENT_TAG=$(aws ec2 --region eu-west-1 describe-tags | grep Value | awk {'print $2'})
aws ec2 create-tags --resources ${INSTANCE_ID} --tags Key=Name,Value=${CURRENT_TAG}_${INSTANCE_ID}
```

Comment: Thanks @Innocent Anigbo. I will try that.